# Postgresql database creation problem with localization

Tags: postgresql, localization, ubuntu

as the output of this command

```
createdb -E UTF8 --lc-collate=hr_HR.UTF8 --lc-ctype=hr_HR.UTF8 tempdb
```

I get

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  invalid locale name hr_HR.UTF8
```

I'm a noob in postgresql so any help will be appreciated! As you can see from above command, I need to create database with support for Croatian language. My OS is:

```
Linux tiho-desktop 2.6.31-20-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP 
Fri Mar 12 04:38:19 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and it is only for development. I plan to move this database to CentOS or something like it for production. I'm using postgresql 8.4.

Thanks in advance,
Tiho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what do you get as the output  of `locale -a | grep hr_HR`?

I can't reproduce the error you get because my `createdb` doesn't accept the locale parameters (seems the option is only [available in 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-createdb.html)), but you should check that the locale you're setting exists in the output of the above command. Also, you don't need to specify the collaction and ctype separately: the `-l` switch covers both.

Comment: Tomislav,

thanks on quick answer. I already solved my problem simply. You have right about localization support on my machine.  The solution for my problem was command: sudo locale-gen hr_HR.UTF-8. :-) Now everything works fine.

P.S.: thanks on observation about -l switch. I'll need it in future. :-)

Thanks again and best regards,
Tiho

Comment: Is there a way to use "locale-gen" or similar on windows as I need to do the same thing ? (I know this is a bit old post but I'm having the same issue with PostgreSQL 9.3.2)

Comment: @khorvat Hi, maybe you can ask this as a new question hew on stackoverflow.